# Why normal objects become reactive automatically in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

In [this article](https://medium.com/@bsalwiczek/ref-vs-reactive-in-vue-3-whats-the-right-choice-7c6f7265ce39) there is an example. It says the normal object wont be 'reactive'.

I made a test in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-thunder-j0tqnp?file=/src/App.vue), and found that changes to the normal object (even the normal string) can automatically change the view.

```html
<template>
  {{ personName }} <!-- will change to Amy, why? -->
  {{ person.name }} <!-- will change to Amy, why? -->
  {{ personRef.name }}
  {{ personReactive.name }}
  <button @click="changeName('Amy')">changeName</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

let personName = "John";
const person = { name: "John" };
const personRef = ref({ name: "John" });
const personReactive = reactive({ name: "John" });
const changeName = (name) => {
  personName = name;
  person.name = name;
  personRef.value.name = name;
  personReactive.name = name;
};
</script>
```

How did this happen? Did I miss something in the Vue document?

I've tried the [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqdUjtvwjAQ/itXL4BEkj0NaVk7dOjsJVgOCY0fsh0QivLfe4d5hFJ1YImc7+G7+3wDW1ub7nvJclYEqWxXBVlyDTAMYKXzRn9WSsI4Ela8JAkc2q4D0VR6KyEYWKvjEg7N8Q2S5N6Y6medX7Kemid4JUK7l3c3b/oQjIZ30bXie8VZLEBdz2dYYrbgrLxhRRb1WLDIJgPjrxeutQG8DL1FpFXWuAADOFkv8RNLwwi1Mwo4w9A4eyVnJ8M0qxWSH6bRJ1YY7S8sMgNQ6/lVAeMvDY6OMiw5f5QuHrTnnsgQj/+6bimgY066BaxKGCjGu/6JQtcFjXE/wPRK+6rrz8/xBz99rStNExdZDLtkSxZzTlRl0x26cBFPDfEz4TnLY4uEnUKn6ZoQrM+zzNeC1nfnU+O2GZ5S1+vQKplKr5KNMwcvHV7MGV2BGzOy8QcVxwQy) which gives the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal variables are *not* becoming reactive. What is really happening is a **re-render** that is caused by the `changeName()` method. The re-render is caused because you changed the values of the reactive variables. As a result, The DOM is updated with the latest values correctly shown for both normal and reactive variables.

To illustrate this I have created a [fork of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-blackburn-u6tued?file=/src/App.vue) with this code:

```js
<template>
  {{ personName }}
  {{ person.name }}
  {{ personRef.name }}
  {{ personReactive.name }}
  <button @click="changeReactiveName('Amy')">changeReactiveName</button>
  <button @click="changeNormalName('Fanoflix')">changeNormalName</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

let personName = "John";
const person = { name: "John" };
const personRef = ref({ name: "John" });
const personReactive = reactive({ name: "John" });

const changeReactiveName = (name) => {
  personRef.value.name = name;
  personReactive.name = name;
};

const changeNormalName = (name) => {
  personName = name;
  person.name = name;
};
</script>
```

When you change only the non-reactive variables by calling `changeNormalName()`, the change (correctly) does not cause a DOM re-render and you will not see the changes reflected in the DOM.

Once you call the `changeReactiveName()` method, the DOM will be re-rendered to incorporate the changes done to the reactive variables. Hence, The DOM will also render the new values of the non-reactive variables which you updated previously and will show `Fanoflix`.

For a better understanding, read how Vue handles rendering: [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html#virtual-dom)